# AUTOSAR rule A5-0-4 stance on pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, polymorphism, autosar

AUTOSAR rule A5-0-4 states

> Pointer arithmetic shall not be used with pointers to non-final
> classes.

It provides the following rationale:

> Pointer arithmetic is only well defined if the pointed-to type of the
> pointer equals the element type of the array it points into, otherwise
> the behavior is undefined. This property can only be guaranteed if the
> pointer operand is a pointer to non-class type or a pointer to final
> class type.

It then gives some examples of compliance and non-compliance. One of the non-compliances has me puzzled:

```cpp
void Foo(Base *start, size_t len)
{
  // Non-Compliant: pointer arithmetic on non-final pointer type
  for (Base *iter = start; iter != start + len; ++iter)
  {
    iter->Do();
  }
}
```

However unlikely it is that anyone would use a plain C-array to store polymorphic pointers, it's in the very fabric of the C++ language.

So my gut feeling is that there is nothing wrong with the above code.

Perhaps I am mistaken in this belief.
Or perhaps I am completely missing the point that this AUTOSAR rule is trying to convey to the reader.

Can someone explain it better than the AUTOSAR document does?

See also [AUTOSAR rule A5-0-4](https://sbmueller.github.io/autosar_cpp_guidelines/A5-0-4.html), which gives the full code used in the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're missing the point. Consider something like this:

```cpp
class Base {
   int x;
public:
   virtual void Do() = 0;
   virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived : public Base {
    int y;
public:
    virtual void Do() override {
         ++y;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived data[10];

    Foo(data, 10); // using definition of `Foo` from question
}
```

This has undefined behavior. `Foo` expects to receive the address of the beginning of an array of `Base`. But we're passing a pointer to `Derived` instead of a pointer to `Base`. Since `Foo` "thinks" it's manipulating pointers to base, when its loop does `++iter`, it's going to increment the address by `sizeof(Base)`.

As we've defined it, however, a `Derived` is almost certainly larger than a `Base`. After the increment `iter` almost certainly **won't** point to the second `Derived` object, and when we try to call `Do` on that pointer, things will go sideways (no guarantee, but in a typical implementation, it'll end up trying to use `data[0].y` as a vtable pointer to find the address of `Do`).

With the code precisely as it stands now, a compiler with decent optimization can probably cover up the problem. Since `Base` has a pure virtual, that can't be instantiated. There's only one class in the program derived from `Base`, so it can conclude that anytime it's dealing with `Base` objects via a pointer (or reference) they must really be instances of `Derived`, and act accordingly.

To be sure of seeing the problem, we sort of need to have two derived classes, preferably of different sizes, and each with its own definition of `Do`, so the compiler can't statically determine that there's only one possible type involved.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base {
protected:
   int x {1};
public:
   virtual void Do() = 0;
   virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
    int y;
public:
    virtual void Do() override {
        ++y;
        std::cout << "x: " << x << ", y: " << y << "\n";
    }
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
    int y;
    int z;
public:
    virtual void Do() override {
        ++z;
        std::cout << "x: " << x << ", y: " << y << ", z: " << z << "\n";
    }
};

void Foo(Base *start, size_t len)
{
  // Non-Compliant: pointer arithmetic on non-final pointer type
  for (Base *iter = start; iter != start + len; ++iter)
  {
    iter->Do();
  }
}

int main() {
    Derived1 data1[10];
    Derived2 data2[10];

    std::cout << "data 1:\n";
    Foo(data1, 10);
    std::cout << "\ndata 2:\n";
    Foo(data2, 10);
}
```

When I attempt to compile/run this, I get:

```
data 1:
x: 1, y: 1
x: 1, y: 32737
x: 1, y: 1
x: 1, y: 1
x: 1, y: 32737
x: 1, y: 0
x: 1, y: 32737
x: 1, y: 32737
x: 1, y: 32737
x: 1, y: 1

data 2:
x: 1, y: 32767, z: -576197143
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So in this case, "goes sideways" translates to a segmentation fault (but you can't entire count on that as the only possible result).

[Execution on Godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/eqvqEEah9) gives a similar result.

Comment: Interesting. It sounds very logical. Yet, it appears to work just fine when I compile and run the program on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/1srKGM3G7). What gcc warning must I enable?

Comment: @iwarv I've edited to include a demonstration of the problem.

Comment: Agreed. Still a shame that it requires static analysis to detect the problem. None of the usual warning settings point this out to me. It looks so "innocent" in itself.

Answer (score 1):

The questioned example would be fine if it were

```
void Foo(Base **start, size_t len);
```

That is with start being of type `Base **`, but as-is each increment is of a `sizeof(Base)` object rather than `sizeof(Base*)`.

Comment: Of course if the calling code has a C-array of polymorphic pointers, such an array would be of type `Base*`. And if you let that array decay to a pointer in calling `Foo()` then this function would need to accept `Base**`. It's actually rather obvious when you think a little deeper. Thanks.